# Rational approximations on the circle

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

The well-known Liouville theorem asserts that an irrational algebraic number $\alpha$ cannot have too good rational approximations, namely $|\alpha-p/q|\ge C(\alpha)/q^k$ where $k$ is the degree of $\alpha$. I wonder whether a similar result holds for the *argument* of an algebraic number that happens to lie on the unit circle.

For example, consider $\theta=\arccos(1/3)$. It is the argument of a root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $x^2-\frac23x+1$. Is there a similar lower bound for $|\theta/\pi-p/q|$, or equivalently, for $|\alpha^q-1|$? (Note that $|\alpha^q-1|\approx q\cdot |\theta/2\pi-p/q|$).

More generally, let $\alpha\in\mathbb C$ be an algebraic number, $|\alpha|=1$ and $\alpha$ is not a root of unity. Is it always true that $|\alpha^q-1|\ge C(\alpha)/q^k$ where $k$ depends only on the degree of $\alpha$ (or perhaps equals the degree minus one)?

Comment: Sergei, Shouldn't both of your `$\le$` signs be `$\ge$`'s?

Comment: @Sergei: I asked Győry who asked Waldschmidt. They think your question is hard, and they don't know the answer. So it is very likely that your question is an open problem.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is affirmative by a result of Fel'dman: An improvement of the estimate of a linear form in the logarithms of algebraic numbers (Russian), Mat. Sb. (N.S.) 77 (119) 1968, 423–436, MR0232736.

See also Theorem 3.1 in Baker's Transcendental Number Theory.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to apply Feldman's result here? I could only get something like $C(\alpha)/q^{\log q}$ from the first theorem cited on the MR page, and an estimate exponential in $q$ from the second one.

Comment: @Sergei: In the second theorem cited on the MR page, $m=2$, $H_0=q$, while $h$ and $n$ are positive constants depending on $\alpha$, so the bound is of the form $>\exp(-c_1-c_2*\ln q)=c_3 q^{-c_2}$ with constants $c_i>0$ depending on $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now. Do you know if the exponent can be bounded in terms of degree of $\alpha$ (not involving height or whatever)?


Comment: @Sergei: Unfortunately I don't know, so I was not completely right saying "the answer is affirmative". The state of the art seems to be set by Matveev (MR1817252) improving on the previous strong result by Baker-Wüstholz (MR1234835). The latter is available online: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0442&DMDID=dmdlog5 I would probably ask the authors of these papers how significant is the dependence on the heights. Probably this dependence is substantial even for $\alpha$ on the unit circle, but I am no expert.